# Syntax Error on Token "int"

Tags: java, integer, syntax-error

I'm new to java (I also know JavaScript and for the last time. I know they aren't the same thing.) working on a personal project of mine and getting an error that doesn't seem to be addressed anywhere else here.

I'm getting a "Syntax Error on Token "int"" On this line of code

```
//if statement
int Random = int(Math.floor(Math.random()*6));}
//else
//...
```

I want "Random" to be a random number 1-6, but I keep getting this error. I've seen other people with a similar problem but they are doing stuff with arrays. And I'm not. How can I fix this?

Comment: That's not valid Java in any way, shape, or form. Cast integer type and make sure Random is declared.

Comment: Java isn't javascript. `Random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6);`

Comment: You are missing a +1 to get 1-6 instead of 0-5.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: It's not exactly valid JavaScript either... `int` isn't even a keyword in it.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you typecast to int in Java.

You should do something like this:

`yourVar = (int) double_value`